# social media icon in right side-bar

Tags: html, css, icons, social-media

I have been created, a shopify website. I need to set social media icon in right-side.

For this i tried [this](https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing-sidebar) website

And here is code:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300
/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-54d2ffc73b704342" async="async"></script>
```

But i need like [**this**](http://www.sparklyfabric.co.uk/) link provided sidebar social icons.

So is there any possible to get free design like this?

Can anyone help me?

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: try this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Horizontal-Floating-Social-Share-Bar/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `css` change

`.atss-left { left: auto; float: left;right: 0; }` and for space between each social icon add  `.atss a { margin:2px; }`

Comment: still nothing change.. here is the code: <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-54d2ffc73b704342" async="async"></script>